# Problem with video resolution streaming through webcam

Tags: opencv, webcam

I have connected Canon powershot G7 max through USB and streaming the output using gphoto2. I am using below command to stream.

gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -threads 5 -f v4l2 /dev/video2

I am using the videocapture through opencv and problem here is the output resolution. The quality of the resolution is very less. Please help!

If more information needed please do ask